# Convert TI TMS320C30 32 bits float to IEEE float in python

Tags: python, floating-point, ieee-754, texas-instruments

I need to convert TI TMS320C30 32 bits float to IEEE float. I found a solution for the inverse problem, but so far I can not achieve anything with the conversion of TMS320C30 32bits float to IEEE 754. Any ideas how to do this?

[Convert IEEE float to TI TMS320C30 32bits float in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17833469/convert-ieee-float-to-ti-tms320c30-32bits-float-in-python)

Comment: The TI documentation linked to in your linked question appears to have all the details on how to do the conversion.  It's gnarly, might take a day of work to do it properly.  Once all the bits are in the proper place, [`struct.pack and struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) would give you the final float.

Answer (score 3):

The [document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra400/spra400.pdf) linked in the previous question provides all necessary details of the TMS320C30 floating-point format: Randy Restle and Adam Cron, "TMS320C30-IEEE Floating-Point Format Converter", Application Report SPRA400, Texas Instruments 1997.

The TMS format does not support infinities, NaNs, signed zeros, or denormals. The 8-bit exponent is stored as a 2's complement integer, not biased as in the IEEE-754 `binary32` format. The significand (mantissa) is stored without the implicit integer bit, which matches IEEE-754. However, for negative operands the significand is basically stored as a negative number.

To convert from the TMS format to the IEEE-754 `binary32` format, we basically need to apply bias to the exponent, negate the significand bits of negative operands (with a correction to the exponent where necessary), and rearrange the order of sign, exponent, and significand fields.

One minor complication is that the TMS format can represent numbers with magnitude < 2<sup>-126</sup> as a normalized floating-point number, while IEEE-754 `binary32` can only store these as subnormals. In this case we need to make the hidden integer bit of the significand visible and denormalize. Since this discards the least significand bit we need to round the result.

I don't know Python, but trust that the ISO-C program below will be easy enough to translate into Python by those skilled in the language. The format conversion works on the bit representation of the respective floating-point formats, which are therefore represented as unsigned 32-bit integers to the conversion function, `tms_to_ieee()`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

uint32_t tms_to_ieee (uint32_t a)
{
    uint32_t frac = a & 0x7fffff;
    uint32_t sign = (a >> 23) & 1;
    uint32_t expo = (a >> 24) & 0xff;
    uint32_t rslt;

    if (expo == 0x80) { // zero or implied zero
        expo = 0;
        frac = 0;
        sign = 0;
    } else {
        /* add IEEE exponent bias of 127 */
        expo = (expo + 0x7f) & 0xff;
        if (sign) {
            /* complement fraction */
            frac = 0x00800000 - frac;
            /* propagate fraction overflow to exponent */
            expo = expo + (frac >> 23);
            /* clear potential overflow */
            frac = frac & 0x7fffff;
        }
        if (expo == 0) {
            /* make implicit integer bit explicit */
            frac = frac + 0x00800000;
            /* denormalize, round to nearest-or-even */
            frac = (frac >> 1) + ((frac & 3) == 3);
        }
    }
    rslt = (sign << 31) | (expo << 23) | frac;
    return rslt;
}

float uint32t_as_float (uint32_t a)
{
    float r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

#define N  (60)  // number of test vectors

int main (void)
{
    uint32_t in[N] = {
        0x7f7fffff,
        0x7f7ffffe,
        0x7f7ffffd,
        0x7f7ffffc,
        0x7f000000,
        0x7e7fffff,
        0x7e7ffffe,
        0x7e7ffffd,
        0x00000000,
        0xff7fffff,
        0xff7ffffe,
        0xff7ffffd,
        0xff000000,
        0xfe7fffff,
        0xfe7ffffe,
        0xfe7ffffd,
        0x82000000,
        0x817fffff,
        0x817ffffe,
        0x817ffffd,
        0x817ffffc,
        0x81000002,
        0x81000001,
        0x81000000,
        0x807fffff,
        0x807ffffe,
        0x807ffffd,
        0x80000001,
        0x80000000,
        0x80ffffff,
        0x80fffffe,
        0x80fffffd,
        0x80800003,
        0x80800002,
        0x80800001,
        0x80800000,
        0x81ffffff,
        0x81fffffe,
        0x81fffffd,
        0x81800002,
        0x81800001,
        0x81800000,
        0x82ffffff,
        0x82fffffe,
        0x82fffffd,
        0xff800001,
        0xff800000,
        0x00ffffff,
        0x00fffffe,
        0x00fffffd,
        0x00800001,
        0x00800000,
        0x01ffffff,
        0x01fffffe,
        0x01fffffd,
        0x7fffffff,
        0x7ffffffe,
        0x7ffffffd,
        0x7f800001,
        0x7f800000,
    };
    float out[N] = {
        (2-exp2(-23)) * exp2(127), 
        (2-exp2(-22)) * exp2(127), 
        (2-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(127), 
        (2-exp2(-21)) * exp2(127),
        exp2(127),
        (2-exp2(-23)) * exp2(126),
        (2-exp2(-22)) * exp2(126),
        (2-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(126),
        1,
        1-exp2(-24),
        1-exp2(-23),
        1-exp2(-22)+exp2(-24),
        exp2(-1),
        (2-exp2(-23)) * exp2(-2),
        (2-exp2(-22)) * exp2(-2),
        (2-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(-2),
        exp2(-126),
        (2-exp2(-23)) * exp2(-127),
        (2-exp2(-22)) * exp2(-127),
        (2-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(-127),
        (2-exp2(-21)) * exp2(-127),
        (1+exp2(-22)) * exp2 (-127),
        (1+exp2(-23)) * exp2 (-127),
        exp2(-127),
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        (-1-exp2(-23)) * exp2(-127),
        (-1-exp2(-22)) * exp2(-127),
        (-1-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(-127),
        (-2+exp2(-22)) * exp2(-127),
        (-2+exp2(-23)) * exp2(-127),
        -exp2(-126),
        (-1-exp2(-23)) * exp2 (-126),
        (-1-exp2(-22)) * exp2 (-126),
        (-1-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2 (-126),
        -1+exp2(-24),
        -exp2(0),
        (-1-exp2(-23)) * exp2(0),
        (-1-exp2(-22)) * exp2(0),
        (-1-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(0),
        -2+exp2(-23),
        -2,
        -2-exp2(-22),
        -2-exp2(-21),
        -2-exp2(-20)+exp2(-22),
        (-1-exp2(-23)) * exp2(127),
        (-1-exp2(-22)) * exp2(127),
        (-1-exp2(-21)+exp2(-23)) * exp2(127),
        (-2+exp2(-23)) * exp2(127),
        -exp2(128)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        uint32_t argi = in [i];;
        uint32_t resi = tms_to_ieee (argi);
        float resf = uint32t_as_float (resi);
        float reff = out[i];
        printf ("tms=%08x  ieee=%08x % 15.8e  ref=% 15.8e  %s\n", 
                argi, resi, resf, reff, (resf == reff) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

The output of the included little test program should look similar to this:

```
tms=7f7fffff  ieee=7f7fffff  3.40282347e+038  ref= 3.40282347e+038  PASS
tms=7f7ffffe  ieee=7f7ffffe  3.40282326e+038  ref= 3.40282326e+038  PASS
tms=7f7ffffd  ieee=7f7ffffd  3.40282306e+038  ref= 3.40282306e+038  PASS
tms=7f7ffffc  ieee=7f7ffffc  3.40282286e+038  ref= 3.40282286e+038  PASS
tms=7f000000  ieee=7f000000  1.70141183e+038  ref= 1.70141183e+038  PASS
tms=7e7fffff  ieee=7effffff  1.70141173e+038  ref= 1.70141173e+038  PASS
tms=7e7ffffe  ieee=7efffffe  1.70141163e+038  ref= 1.70141163e+038  PASS
tms=7e7ffffd  ieee=7efffffd  1.70141153e+038  ref= 1.70141153e+038  PASS
tms=00000000  ieee=3f800000  1.00000000e+000  ref= 1.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=ff7fffff  ieee=3f7fffff  9.99999940e-001  ref= 9.99999940e-001  PASS
tms=ff7ffffe  ieee=3f7ffffe  9.99999881e-001  ref= 9.99999881e-001  PASS
tms=ff7ffffd  ieee=3f7ffffd  9.99999821e-001  ref= 9.99999821e-001  PASS
tms=ff000000  ieee=3f000000  5.00000000e-001  ref= 5.00000000e-001  PASS
tms=fe7fffff  ieee=3effffff  4.99999970e-001  ref= 4.99999970e-001  PASS
tms=fe7ffffe  ieee=3efffffe  4.99999940e-001  ref= 4.99999940e-001  PASS
tms=fe7ffffd  ieee=3efffffd  4.99999911e-001  ref= 4.99999911e-001  PASS
tms=82000000  ieee=00800000  1.17549435e-038  ref= 1.17549435e-038  PASS
tms=817fffff  ieee=00800000  1.17549435e-038  ref= 1.17549435e-038  PASS
tms=817ffffe  ieee=007fffff  1.17549421e-038  ref= 1.17549421e-038  PASS
tms=817ffffd  ieee=007ffffe  1.17549407e-038  ref= 1.17549407e-038  PASS
tms=817ffffc  ieee=007ffffe  1.17549407e-038  ref= 1.17549407e-038  PASS
tms=81000002  ieee=00400001  5.87747316e-039  ref= 5.87747316e-039  PASS
tms=81000001  ieee=00400000  5.87747175e-039  ref= 5.87747175e-039  PASS
tms=81000000  ieee=00400000  5.87747175e-039  ref= 5.87747175e-039  PASS
tms=807fffff  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=807ffffe  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=807ffffd  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80000001  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80000000  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80ffffff  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80fffffe  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80fffffd  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80800003  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80800002  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80800001  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=80800000  ieee=00000000  0.00000000e+000  ref= 0.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=81ffffff  ieee=80400000 -5.87747175e-039  ref=-5.87747175e-039  PASS
tms=81fffffe  ieee=80400001 -5.87747316e-039  ref=-5.87747316e-039  PASS
tms=81fffffd  ieee=80400002 -5.87747456e-039  ref=-5.87747456e-039  PASS
tms=81800002  ieee=807fffff -1.17549421e-038  ref=-1.17549421e-038  PASS
tms=81800001  ieee=80800000 -1.17549435e-038  ref=-1.17549435e-038  PASS
tms=81800000  ieee=80800000 -1.17549435e-038  ref=-1.17549435e-038  PASS
tms=82ffffff  ieee=80800001 -1.17549449e-038  ref=-1.17549449e-038  PASS
tms=82fffffe  ieee=80800002 -1.17549463e-038  ref=-1.17549463e-038  PASS
tms=82fffffd  ieee=80800003 -1.17549477e-038  ref=-1.17549477e-038  PASS
tms=ff800001  ieee=bf7fffff -9.99999940e-001  ref=-9.99999940e-001  PASS
tms=ff800000  ieee=bf800000 -1.00000000e+000  ref=-1.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=00ffffff  ieee=bf800001 -1.00000012e+000  ref=-1.00000012e+000  PASS
tms=00fffffe  ieee=bf800002 -1.00000024e+000  ref=-1.00000024e+000  PASS
tms=00fffffd  ieee=bf800003 -1.00000036e+000  ref=-1.00000036e+000  PASS
tms=00800001  ieee=bfffffff -1.99999988e+000  ref=-1.99999988e+000  PASS
tms=00800000  ieee=c0000000 -2.00000000e+000  ref=-2.00000000e+000  PASS
tms=01ffffff  ieee=c0000001 -2.00000024e+000  ref=-2.00000024e+000  PASS
tms=01fffffe  ieee=c0000002 -2.00000048e+000  ref=-2.00000048e+000  PASS
tms=01fffffd  ieee=c0000003 -2.00000072e+000  ref=-2.00000072e+000  PASS
tms=7fffffff  ieee=ff000001 -1.70141204e+038  ref=-1.70141204e+038  PASS
tms=7ffffffe  ieee=ff000002 -1.70141224e+038  ref=-1.70141224e+038  PASS
tms=7ffffffd  ieee=ff000003 -1.70141244e+038  ref=-1.70141244e+038  PASS
tms=7f800001  ieee=ff7fffff -3.40282347e+038  ref=-3.40282347e+038  PASS
tms=7f800000  ieee=ff800000 -1.#INF0000e+000  ref=-1.#INF0000e+000  PASS
```